# I have more than one svg in some boxes, I want to only change the color, on the one that I click

Tags: jquery, svg

I have some svg's I want to change their fill on click, but I want it only change the color, on the one that I click, each svg have the same class and id's, but are in different divs/boxes

```
 $('svg').on("click", function() {
        $('.cls-1').css("fill","#8b5a0b");
 });
```

Comment: can you provide some html markup please!

Comment: Multiple ids with the same value would make your document invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this)` inside event handler to get the element on which the event was fired.

```js
$('svg').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('fill', '#8b5a0b');
});
```